# Python, structure for looking and extracting similarities. List. Dictionary or DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, list, types

I have some measurements currently stored in an array:

```
    myMatrix[:5,:5]
    Out[11]: 
    array([[192., 192.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
    [185., 171.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
    [ 17.,   1.,  16.,  17.,   1.],
    [185., 185.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
    [185., 185.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
```

I would like to write a function that works row-wise and finds similarities.

The input of the function should be variable, for example, an expected input can be just the *192* or *185,185*.

Based on that input, the algorithm should search (a `for` loop I guess) on the entries that have the first column (for the input *192*, that will be the first column, for the input *185,185*, that will be the first two columns) and return me back the lines where the matching is.

For example, for the input *185,185*, the two last rows should be returned.

What will be the best data type thatI should write the code for?

So far I know dictionaries, Lists and DataFrames. I have also seed DataFrames integrating dictionaries. I would be inclined to use pandas data frames but I am not sure how they can handle variable number of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas and numpy in this case.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[192., 192.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
    [185., 171.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
    [ 17.,   1.,  16.,  17.,   1.],
    [185., 185.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
    [185., 185.,   0.,   0.,   0.]]), 
columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

Comment: Thanks I started working with that. So far I was able to find rows based on fixed columns queries. I also noticed that in pd.DataFrame I can name the columns with integers with helps a lot with the indexing in my code. My remaining question will be how to handle different length of inputs. For example for an input of length two
 inputs=[185,0]
I can use the below to pick the rows.
selection = smallData[(smallData[0]==inputs[0]) & (smallData[1]==inputs[1])]


How to handle though different length of inputs? Where length goes from 1 to large numbers?


P.S Cant vote yet but thanks again

Comment: Well, technically this different lengths will be implemented via null vlaues. You can have NULL data inputs. So, if there's no input, the data is NULL. Then you can handle this NULL date various ways :) It's up to you. You can drop null values, or convert them to different numbers, values, whatever.

Comment: So, if the row is: [185., 171.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
and you do input only for two values, e.g. 185,185, it can look this way:
[185., 185.,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL],

Comment: Here is great manual on NULL values or missing data: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.04-missing-values.html

Comment: NULL values may look differently, NaN, None, NiLL, whatever, the meaning is the same, I usually call them simply NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you requirement and knowledge. For a tiny dataset, the way you know will be the fastest to write a code giving the solution. If you want to experiment with pandas, or if the dataset is large, pandas is certainly an nice way because is can directly use the numpy array.

Here you could use:

```
def find_start(mat, *val):
    # convert the argument list to a ndarray of right type
    s = np.array(val, dtype = mat.dtype)
    # compare the start of each line with that ndarray (assuming s is shorter than the line)
    return (df.iloc(1)[0:len(s)] == s).agg(all, axis=1)
```

Then with your example data:

```
>>> print(find_start(myMatrix, 192))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
>>> print(find_start(myMatrix, 185, 185.))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I had to slightly edit the code to make it work for me. So by using this command

[(smallData.iloc(1)[0:i] == s).agg(all, axis=1)]

I can get the lines where the input is the same

[0     True
 1    False
 2     True
 3     True
 4     True
 dtype: bool]

How I can further use now these indexes to pick from the original Table the rows?